# How do I extend an element's height past 100vh to include the entire scrollable area?

Tags: html, css

When my site loads, it has a scrollbar with some content beneath the 100vh limit that can be accessed by scrolling as per usual. I have an element (mdl drawer menu) that only reaches 100%, or 100vh. When I open this menu I want it to extend all the way down to the end of the page, including the scroll area, so that when I scroll down the menu still exists on the side. How can I go about doing this? It seems the whole body element is fixed at 100vw 100vh as well.

Here is the index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js">
</script>


<div class="demo-layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--transparent">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">foo</span>
    </header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title" style="font-size:20px">Navigation</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#card1">foo</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#card2">foo</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#card3">foo</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    </main>
    </div>

    <div class='cards'>
        <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" id="card1">
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">foo</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                foo
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" id="card2">
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">foo</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                foo
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" id="card3">
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">foo</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
              foo
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        function close() {
            var d = document.querySelector(".mdl-layout");
            d.MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();
            console.log('a')
        }

        document.querySelector(".mdl-navigation").addEventListener("click", close);
    </script>
```

And styles.css:

```
    html {
    /*background: url('https://i.redd.it/8qxg1uomq2f31.jpg') center center fixed;*/
    background: url('https://i.redd.it/xcork1aobaa31.jpg') center center fixed;
    background-size: 100vw;
}

.demo-card-wide {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
    width: 30vw;
}

.demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__title {
    color: #fff;
    height: 150px;
    /*background: url('https://i.redd.it/xcork1aobaa31.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;*/
    background: url('https://i.redd.it/7zebjsi4m8a31.jpg') fixed;
    background-size: 100vw;
}

.demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__menu {
    color: #fff;
}

.demo-layout-transparent {}

.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__header,
.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
    /* This background is dark, so we set text to white. Use 87% black instead if
    your background is light. */
    color: white;
}

.cards {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 35vw;
}

#fcard {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

.material-icons {
    font-size: 50px;
}

.mdl-layout-title {
    font-size: 60px;
}

.mdl-layout__obfuscator.is-visible {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

.mdl-layout__drawer {
    transition-duration: .1s;
}

.mdl-card__title-text {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to add `position: fixed` to `.mdl-layout__drawer.is-visible`:

```css
html {
  /*background: url('https://i.redd.it/8qxg1uomq2f31.jpg') center center fixed;*/
  background: url('https://i.redd.it/xcork1aobaa31.jpg') center center fixed;
  background-size: 100vw;
}

.demo-card-wide {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
  width: 30vw;
}

.demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__title {
  color: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  /*background: url('https://i.redd.it/xcork1aobaa31.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;*/
  background: url('https://i.redd.it/7zebjsi4m8a31.jpg') fixed;
  background-size: 100vw;
}

.demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__menu {
  color: #fff;
}

.demo-layout-transparent {}

.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__header,
.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
  /* This background is dark, so we set text to white. Use 87% black instead if
    your background is light. */
  color: white;
}

.cards {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 35vw;
}

#fcard {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.mdl-layout-title {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.mdl-layout__obfuscator.is-visible {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

.mdl-layout__drawer {
  transition-duration: .1s;
}

.mdl-layout__drawer.is-visible {
    position: fixed;
}

.mdl-card__title-text {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js">
  </script>


  <div class="demo-layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--transparent">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">foo</span>
    </header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title" style="font-size:20px">Navigation</span>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#card1">foo</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#card2">foo</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#card3">foo</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    </main>
    </div>

    <div class='cards'>
      <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" id="card1">
        <div class="mdl-card__title">
          <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">foo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
          foo
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" id="card2">
        <div class="mdl-card__title">
          <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">foo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
          foo
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" id="card3">
        <div class="mdl-card__title">
          <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">foo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
          foo
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script>
      function close() {
        var d = document.querySelector(".mdl-layout");
        d.MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();
        console.log('a')
      }

      document.querySelector(".mdl-navigation").addEventListener("click", close);
    </script>
```

Note that you need to add it to `.mdl-layout__drawer.is-visible` and not just `.mdl-layout__drawer` directly, as Material Design targets the same element (applying `position: absolute`) with higher [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!